# what is wrong with my if condition? it doesn't return the right value. in this case it should return 'F'. (Matching 1D Array)

Tags: arrays, c, if-statement, return, function-definition

The function should return 'T' if each element in the first array is equal to it corresponding element in the second array, and return 'F' if there is any difference between two array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char match_array(int a[10], int b[10]);

int main()
{    
    int a1[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    int a2[10] = {0,0,0,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    char match;

    match = match_array(a1, a2);    
    printf("%c", match);
    
    return 0;
}

char match_array(int a[10], int b[10])
{
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<10; i++){
        if(a[i] == b[i]){
            return 'T';
        }
    }
    return 'F';
}
```

Comment: `if(a[i] == b[i])` This returns `T` if *any* of the corresponding array entries are equal. You need to flip that around and return `F` if any are *not* equal.

Comment: i understand what you mean, but there is no way that it gives me the right answer when i used the condition i post right?? And thanks for your help.

Comment: Not sure what you mean and why you need to ask that again. The results clearly show the code is wrong and I wouldn't tell you to change the logic if it were correct already.

Comment: i understand, thanks for your help.

Comment: Range-based equivalence checks are *always* about detecting per-element non-equivalence and ejecting early, otherwise returning equivalent once the range is exhausted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your code for `match_array` once again clearly.

```
char match_array(int a[10], int b[10])
{
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<10; i++){
        if(a[i] == b[i]){
            return 'T';
        }
    }
    return 'F';
}
```

Here whenever two corresponding elements of array are equal, you are returning `T`. Which means, return `true` when 'any' two corresponding elements are equal. I guess, this is not you intended. To return `true` when 'all' corresponding elements are equal, you should modify your code to this:

```
char match_array(int a[10], int b[10])
{
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<10; i++){
        if(a[i] != b[i]){
            return 'F';
        }
    }
    return 'T';
}
```

Here whenever, two corresponding elements are unequal, you would return `false`. You should return `true` only when you have iterated over entire array, and found that no elements are unequal.

Comment: now it make sense, thanks for your help, really appreciate it.

Comment: Glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) for more information. Welcome to StackOverflow !!

Answer (score 0):

Your run your loop

```
for(i=0; i<10; i++){
        if(a[i] == b[i]){
            return 'T';
        }
    }
    return 'F';
```

Which goes through the arrays and check each pair.
It will return T when (and if) it'll reach a pair that is equal, which means in our case:
**a[3] & b[3] == 4**

It will return true and that's it. it won't reach the end of the loop because return statement stops the function and returns the return value.

The only way it will return `F` in this case is there is no equal pair in the arrays, which isn't the case here.

To simplify it:
Your algorithm here is:

```
check if a[i] == b[i]:
if yes - stop function return true
if no - continue loop and check a[i+1] == b[i+i]

if reached here -  return F.
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, it was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For starters the function should be declared like

```
char match_array( const int a[], const int b[], size_t n );
```

That is the function should be able to deal with arrays of various sizes.

And its parameters that denote arrays shall have the qualifier `const` because passed arrays are not changed within the function.

Your function returns `'T'` as soon as there are found two elements of the arrays equal each other though all other elements can be unequal each other.

```
for(i=0; i<10; i++){
    if(a[i] == b[i]){
        return 'T';
    }
}
```

The function can be defined the following way

```
char match_array( const int a[], const int b[], size_t n )
{
    size_t i = 0;

    while ( i < n && a[i] == b[i] ) ++i;

    return i == n ? 'T' : 'F';
}
```

And the function is called like

```
match = match_array( a1, a2, 10 );
```